# robot framework - extracting test cases from a file

Tags: robotframework

I have a Test Template which needs few arguments as an input. 
I want to separate all the data for the test (=the test cases) in a separate file, no matter what type of a file (CSV/Variable file). How can I do that in the most elegant way?
Thanks.
Just to be more specific:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Login with invalid credentials should fail

*** Test Cases ***                USERNAME         PASSWORD             ...       ....      ....
Invalid User Name                 invalid          ${VALID PASSWORD}
Invalid Password                  ${VALID USER}    invalid
Invalid User Name and Password    invalid          invalid
Empty User Name                   ${EMPTY}         ${VALID PASSWORD}
Empty Password                    ${VALID USER}    ${EMPTY}
Empty User Name and Password      ${EMPTY}         ${EMPTY}
.
.
.
.
```

I have a lot of test cases and especially a lot of columns which some cells could contain a long text - not elegant to view on a .robot file. 
So I want to load the test cases from a separate file, which has a format suitable for large amount of data and columns.
I'll be happy to know if someone could think of an elegant way to to this.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you give a small, concrete example?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: It sounds like you have asked a duplicate of [In Robot Framework, how to perform data-driven testing by creating a separate test case for each line of data in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182794/in-robot-framework-how-to-perform-data-driven-testing-by-creating-a-separate-te) and/or [Can we write test cases in CSV OR Excel file in Robot Framework and execute just by reading CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443520/can-we-write-test-cases-in-csv-or-excel-file-in-robot-framework-and-execute-just). Am I correct?